# Save 10,000 digits of string to text document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am relatively new to python3 and I just got the code for a string that adds one number to the previous number, and adds that number onto the previous number as a string

For example if the first number was 1, it would 1+1 to equal 2 and attach that to the string to make 12.

The first few digits of the number would be
123456789101112131415161718...

I have the code

```
from itertools import count
for c in count():
print(c, end="")
```

And I am wondering if there is a way to stop it at a certain amount of digits lets say 10,000 and then save it to a document called number.txt

Comment: sure, show us your flaw, and given you are using python, make sure you post it using the code tags so we can see your proper indentation.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this. Try searching for `random number python` or similar...

Comment: @Shadow the numbers aren't random

Comment: @cricket_007 - You're right. Then `itertools.counter` might be the way to go then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the answers so far are very memory intensive, or quite finite.

I would consider the [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) generator and printing the results immediately. This will use very little memory, and is by far the most 'infinite' of the solutions posted so far.

```
from itertools import count
for c in count():
    print(c, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k = ""

for i in range(0, 100):

    k = k + ''.join(str(i))

print(k)
```

will create till from 0 to 100 like so

0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899